# Issue with export-graphml command

Tags: neo4j, graphml

I am using Neo4j-CE-3.0.3 version in Windows and I'm trying to export graphml. 
I have used neo4j shell tools available in below link
https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools

I unzipped the files to lib folder as well. Then in neo4j-shell, i tried to run export-graphml using command

```
export-graphml -o out.graphml Match (u:U)-[:ACC]-(p:P{pID:'100'}) where p.pID<>'0' return u.uID, p.pID,count(*) as ACCESSED order by ACCESSED desc
```

But I am getting an error

> Unknown command 'export-graphml'

help command is retrieving commands

> Available commands: alias begin call cd commit create cypher dbinfo drop dump env explain export foreach gsh help index jsh load ls man match merge mknode mkrel mv optional paths planner profile pwd return rm rmnode rmrel rollback runtime schema set start trav unwind using with
>
> Use man  for info about each command.

Lib folder has below jars 
    import-tools-3.0.3.jar , reflectasm-1.10.1.jar , opencsv-2.3.jar , objenesis-2.1.jar , minlog-1.3.0.jar , mapdb-0.9.3.jar , kryo-3.0.3.jar , geoff-0.5.0.jar

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you update your question with the content of your `lib` directory, as well as the environment you're running Neo4j on (Linux, Windows, MacOS X)?

Initially, mine (Unix version) has:

> asm-5.0.2.jar
>   bcpkix-jdk15on-1.53.jar
>   bcprov-jdk15on-1.53.jar
>   commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
>   commons-configuration-1.10.jar
>   commons-digester-2.1.jar
>   commons-io-2.4.jar
>   commons-lang-2.6.jar
>   commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar
>   commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
>   concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.2.jar
>   jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
>   jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar
>   jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
>   javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
>   jersey-core-1.19.jar
>   jersey-multipart-1.19.jar
>   jersey-server-1.19.jar
>   jersey-servlet-1.19.jar
>   jetty-http-9.2.9.v20150224.jar
>   jetty-io-9.2.9.v20150224.jar
>   jetty-security-9.2.9.v20150224.jar
>   jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar
>   jetty-servlet-9.2.9.v20150224.jar
>   jetty-util-9.2.9.v20150224.jar
>   jetty-webapp-9.2.9.v20150224.jar
>   jetty-xml-9.2.9.v20150224.jar
>   jline-2.12.jar
>   jsr311-api-1.1.2.r612.jar
>   lucene-analyzers-common-5.5.0.jar
>   lucene-codecs-5.5.0.jar
>   lucene-core-5.5.0.jar
>   lucene-queryparser-5.5.0.jar
>   mimepull-1.9.3.jar
>   neo4j-bolt-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-browser-1.1.6.jar
>   neo4j-codegen-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-collections-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-common-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-consistency-check-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-csv-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-cypher-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.3-2.3.4.jar
>   neo4j-cypher-compiler-3.0-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-cypher-frontend-2.3-2.3.4.jar
>   neo4j-cypher-frontend-3.0-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-dbms-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-graph-algo-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-graph-matching-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-graphdb-api-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-import-tool-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-io-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-jmx-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-kernel-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-logging-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-lucene-index-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-lucene-upgrade-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-primitive-collections-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-resource-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-security-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-server-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-shell-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-udc-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-unsafe-3.0.3.jar
>   netty-all-4.0.28.Final.jar
>   opencsv-2.3.jar
>   parboiled-core-1.1.7.jar
>   parboiled-scala_2.11-1.1.7.jar
>   rhino-1.7R4.jar
>   scala-library-2.11.8.jar
>   scala-reflect-2.11.8.jar
>   server-api-3.0.3.jar

In neo4j-shell, running `help` lists:

> Available commands: alias begin call cd commit create cypher dbinfo drop dump env explain export foreach gsh help index jsh load ls man match merge mknode mkrel mv optional paths planner profile pwd return rm rmnode rmrel rollback runtime schema set start trav unwind using with

After unzipping the neo4j-shell-tools, I correctly have the 3 extra libs (`opencsv-2.3.jar` is already included in the distribution):

> asm-5.0.2.jar
>   bcpkix-jdk15on-1.53.jar
>   bcprov-jdk15on-1.53.jar
>   commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
>   commons-configuration-1.10.jar
>   commons-digester-2.1.jar
>   commons-io-2.4.jar
>   commons-lang-2.6.jar
>   commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar
>   commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
>   concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.2.jar
>   **geoff-0.5.0.jar**
>   **import-tools-3.0.1.jar**
>   jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
>   jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar
>   jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
>   javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
>   jersey-core-1.19.jar
>   jersey-multipart-1.19.jar
>   jersey-server-1.19.jar
>   jersey-servlet-1.19.jar
>   jetty-http-9.2.9.v20150224.jar
>   jetty-io-9.2.9.v20150224.jar
>   jetty-security-9.2.9.v20150224.jar
>   jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar
>   jetty-servlet-9.2.9.v20150224.jar
>   jetty-util-9.2.9.v20150224.jar
>   jetty-webapp-9.2.9.v20150224.jar
>   jetty-xml-9.2.9.v20150224.jar
>   jline-2.12.jar
>   jsr311-api-1.1.2.r612.jar
>   lucene-analyzers-common-5.5.0.jar
>   lucene-codecs-5.5.0.jar
>   lucene-core-5.5.0.jar
>   lucene-queryparser-5.5.0.jar
>   **mapdb-0.9.3.jar**
>   mimepull-1.9.3.jar
>   neo4j-bolt-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-browser-1.1.6.jar
>   neo4j-codegen-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-collections-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-common-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-consistency-check-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-csv-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-cypher-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.3-2.3.4.jar
>   neo4j-cypher-compiler-3.0-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-cypher-frontend-2.3-2.3.4.jar
>   neo4j-cypher-frontend-3.0-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-dbms-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-graph-algo-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-graph-matching-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-graphdb-api-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-import-tool-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-io-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-jmx-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-kernel-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-logging-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-lucene-index-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-lucene-upgrade-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-primitive-collections-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-resource-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-security-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-server-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-shell-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-udc-3.0.3.jar
>   neo4j-unsafe-3.0.3.jar
>   netty-all-4.0.28.Final.jar
>   opencsv-2.3.jar
>   parboiled-core-1.1.7.jar
>   parboiled-scala_2.11-1.1.7.jar
>   rhino-1.7R4.jar
>   scala-library-2.11.8.jar
>   scala-reflect-2.11.8.jar
>   server-api-3.0.3.jar

Now, running `help` in neo4j-shell lists:

> Available commands: alias auto-index begin call cd commit create cypher dbinfo drop dump env eval explain export **export-cypher export-graphml** foreach gsh help **import-cypher import-geoff import-graphml** index jsh load ls man match merge mknode mkrel mv optional paths planner profile pwd return rm rmnode rmrel rollback runtime schema set start trav unwind using with

---

### Update

The content of your `lib` directory is really dubious: in addition to the libs from neo4j-shell-tools, you only have 4 other jars, none of which appear in a regular Neo4j installation, and none of the Neo4j jars themselves.

Are you really sure you're unzipping in **Neo4j's** `lib` directory, and not a `lib` directory in your home or something? It definitely doesn't look like Neo4j.

I don't know if you've installed the Windows version of Neo4j using the .exe or .zip, but I downloaded the .zip to check and it contains the `neo4j-community-3.0.3\lib` directory, hopefully the .exe extracts a similar directory structure. That's where you should put the extra jars from neo4j-shell-tools.

Comment: I'm using neo4j in Windows. below are the jar files in lib folder          import-tools-3.0.3.jar , reflectasm-1.10.1.jar , opencsv-2.3.jar , objenesis-2.1.jar , minlog-1.3.0.jar , mapdb-0.9.3.jar , kryo-3.0.3.jar , geoff-0.5.0.jar